# SSRS Working With Time Zone

Tags: reporting-services, datepicker, timezone, ssrs-2008, timezone-offset

I have an issue with in DB when retrieving a field CreatedDate, the result have a difference of 5 hours. In starting i used DATEADD function.

```
DATEADD(HOUR, 5, IncidentDimvw.CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
```

Id  -  DataBaseCreatedDate  -  EditedCreatedDate

IR21   -  02/02/2013 09:04:56 PM   -  03/02/2013 02:04:56 AM

IR67    - 03/02/2013 06:02:02 AM  -   03/02/2013 11:02:02 AM

IR78    - 03/02/2013 09:22:44 PM   -  04/02/2013  02:22:44 AM

When Run the query after Selecting @StartDate = 03/02/2013 and @EndDate = 03/02/2013

It gives me two results IR21 and IR67

EditedCreatedDate is actually Orignal Incident Created Date And Time

But, when i use date range filter here i face some issues on timing like; if i select @startdate =  06/20/2013 (06/20/2013 00:00:00 AM actually it picks up this time)

There Should be some timezone problem kindly help me on this issue as i have no idea how to resolve it. May be it helps if i apply (@timezone) filter but unfortunetly where to apply this filter i donot know.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGl96.png)

Comment: The dates your clients are sending will have to be converted to UTC or your servers time. From there you will need to implement the conversion process. If you already have localization functions like UTCTimeToLocalTime(timeZone) or LocalTimeToUTCTime(timeZone) then I would suggest adding that assembly into your report. If not you will have to manually add your TZ calcs in SQL :( This can become cumbersome without a proven method for dynamic day light savings conversions. Currently I am in EST in the US and calculations are GMT-4. However, at some point and time that will change to GMT-5.

Comment: Thanks Lrb,
There should be localization functions is. Because SCSM Default reports shows the converted time exactly the incident creation time have. But I do not know how to add that assembly into my reports. Or you can give me any reference link.

Comment: When you save a record is the CreatedDate being stored using the servers local time GETDATE()? Or is the users configured locale being used in the calculation - are you sending in the CreatedDate from logic that takes the users tz into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i got some in the regard of my question.
The steps below to add assembly.
 1.In Design view, right-click the design surface outside the border of the report and click Report Properties. 
2.Click References. 
3.In Add or remove assemblies, click Add and then click the ellipsis button to browse to the assembly.

In you scenario, if you want to add timezone assembly, you can add System.Core. For the detail information about it, please see:

[Working with Time Zones in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969689/working-with-time-zones-in-ssrs)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Muhammad Ahsan Misbah